# Creating a multidimensional array of files and modified dates

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here's the project: I'm creating a PHP script to optimize images in a folder. I'm grabbing all the JPGs from the folder, getting their modified date and filename, and pushing them into an array; this array is being iterated through for the compression, as well as eventually being output into a json file for later checks to make sure I don't optimize an image again if it isn't needed.

Problem: my inner arrays are empty when I print_r.

I'm not as strong a backend dev as I am frontend, so I'm a little weak with multidimensional associative arrays in PHP.

```
if (is_dir($imgFolder)){
    if ($dh = opendir($imgFolder)){
        $imgIndex = 0;
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            if (strpos($file, '.jpg') !== false){
                $imgDate = filemtime($imgFolder . $file);

                array_push($imgFiles, 
                    array($imgIndex => array(
                        [lastmod] => $imgDate, [filename] => $file)
                    )
                );

                $imgIndex++;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Basically, I want the values to be like this..

```
[0]
  [lastmod]=>date1
  [filename]=>file1.jpg
[1]
  [lastmod]=>date2
  [filename]=>file2.jpg
[2]
  [lastmod]=>date3
  [filename]=>file3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
if (strpos($file, '.jpg') !== false){
    $imgFiles[] = [ 
        'lastmod' => filemtime($imgFolder . $file), 
        'filename' => $file,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Fantastic; that worked great. I knew I was overengineering the solution.